# TortoiseHg proxy sample

Tags: mercurial, proxy, tortoisehg

Can anyone show me the sample of proxy setting in TortoiseHg?
I can't configure it right, because don't know what's section name, what's the key name

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need in the documentation : [Proxy settings](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/settings.html#module-proxy.settings).